# This swift code is not working, can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofireobjectmapper

I a'm working in a old project

This code is not working, can someone tell me what i am doing wrong ?
The json is returning from API, but the object is not being created (parsing json to class)

podfile

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'RealTimeBalance' do

  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
  pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3.3'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'PKHUD', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'lottie-ios'
  
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  # Pods for RealTimeBalance

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk-iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

// Class ViewController
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        RealTimeBalanceService.getRealTimeBalance(success: { result in
//            if result. {
//                print("call failure 1")
//            }
            
            let balance = result
            print(result.code)
            
        }, failure: { error in
            print("call failure 22")
            print(error)
            
        })
    }


}
```

// Class RealTimeBalanceService
import Foundation

```
class RealTimeBalanceService: NSObject {
    static func getRealTimeBalance(success: @escaping(_ balance: RealTimeBalance) -> Void,
                                   failure: @escaping(_ error: String) -> Void) {
        let request = Router.getAccounts
        
        Network.requestObject(request: request, type: RealTimeBalance.self) { result in
            switch result {
            case let .success(data):
                success(data)
            case let .failure( error):
                failure(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

// Class Network.swift

```
import Foundation

import ObjectMapper
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import PKHUD
import SwiftyJSON

enum NetworkError: LocalizedError {
    case http(error: Error)
    case custom(description: String)
    case objectSerialization
    
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case let .http(error): return error.localizedDescription
        case let .custom(description): return description
        case .objectSerialization: return "Could not serialize JSON into object.."
        }
    }
}

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(NetworkError)
}

enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .getAccounts:
            return API.Home.getAccounts
        }
    }
    var parameters: Any {
        var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
        parameters["username"] = "username"
        
        return parameters
    }
    var encoding: ParameterEncoding {
        switch self {
        case .getAccounts:
            return URLEncoding.httpBody
        }
    }
    
    var arrayEncoding: ArrayEncoding {
        return ArrayEncoding()
    }
    var method: HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .getAccounts:
            return .get
        }
    }
    
    var headers: HTTPHeaders {
        var headers: [String: String] = [:]
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        
        return headers
    }
    
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = try API.baseURL.asURL()
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path.replacingOccurrences(of: "", with: "")))
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 60
        
//        if let params = self.parameters as? [String: Any] {
//            return try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: params.asParameters())
//        } else {
            if let params = self.parameters as? [[String: String]] {
                return try arrayEncoding.encode(urlRequest, with: params.asParameters())
            }
            
            let params = self.parameters as? [Int]
            return try arrayEncoding.encode(urlRequest, with: params?.asParameters() ?? [:])
        //}
    }
    
    case getAccounts
}

struct API {
    struct Home {
        static let getAccounts = "/getbalance"
    }
    static var serverUrl: String {
        return "http://localhost:3000"
    }
    static let baseURL = serverUrl
}

class Network {
    class func requestObject<T: Mappable>(request: URLRequestConvertible,
                                          type: T.Type,
                                          completion: @escaping (Result<T>) -> Void) {

                Alamofire.request(request)
                    .responseString(completionHandler: { print($0) })
                    .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ObjectResult<T>>) in
                        //if App.Network.debug { printLog(response) }
                        
                        switch response.result {
                        case let .success(value):
                            
                            let code = response.response?.statusCode ?? 0
                            
                            if value.success && code >= 200 && code <= 299 {
                                guard let result = value.result else {
                                    completion(.failure(NetworkError.custom(description: "Unexpected error. Please contact account officer.")))
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                completion(.success(result))
                            } else {
                                if code == 401 {
                                    if value.type == "sessionExpired" {
                                        //unauthenticated()
                                        return
                                    } else if value.type == "apiAuthenticated" {
                                        //AuthService.fetchAuth(success: { auth in
                                        //    Session.shared.auth = auth
                                        requestObject(request: request, type: type, completion: completion)
                                        //}, failure: { error in
                                        //    completion(.failure(NetworkError.custom(description: error)))
                                        //})
                                        return
                                    }
                                }
                                completion(.failure(NetworkError.custom(description: value.message)))
                            }
                        case let .failure(error):
                            // let code = response.response?statusCode
                            
                            /*if code == 401
                                unauthenticated()
                             
                                return
                            }*/
                            completion(.failure(NetworkError.http(error: error)))
                        }
                    }
        
    }
    

}

class ObjectResult<T: Mappable> : BaseResult {
    var result: T?
    var hasResult: Bool = false
    
    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map: map)
        hasResult = map.JSON.contains(where: { $0.key == "Return" })
        result <- map["Return"]
    }
}

class BaseResult: Mappable {
    var type: String = ""
    var success: Bool = false
    var message: String = ""
    
    init () {
        
    }
    
    required convenience init(map: Map) {
        self.init()
        self.mapping(map: map)
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        type <- map["Type"]
        success <- map["Success"]
        message <- map["Message"]
    }
}
```

// Class RealTimeBalance.swift
I am suspicious that it is this model that was made wrong

```
import ObjectMapper

// MARK: - RealTimeBalance
class RealTimeBalance: NSObject, NSCoding, Mappable {
    
    var code: Int?
    var data: DataClass?

    init(code: Int?, data: DataClass?) {
        self.code = code
        self.data = data
    }

    override init() {
        
    }
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }
    
    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.code = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "code") as? Int ?? 0
        self.data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "data") as? DataClass
        
    }
    
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(code, forKey: "code")
        aCoder.encode(data, forKey: "data")
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        code <- map["code"]
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}

// MARK: - DataClass
class DataClass: NSObject, NSCoding, Mappable {
    
    var account: Account?
    var balance: Balance?
    var balanceSource: String?

    init(account: Account?, balance: Balance?, balanceSource: String?) {
        self.account = account
        self.balance = balance
        self.balanceSource = balanceSource
    }
    
    override init() {
        
    }
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }
    
    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.account = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "account") as? Account
        self.balance = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "balance") as? Balance
        self.balanceSource = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "balance") as? String
    }
    
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(account, forKey: "account")
        aCoder.encode(balance, forKey: "balance")
        aCoder.encode(balanceSource, forKey: "balanceSource")
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        account <- map["account"]
        balance <- map["balance"]
        balanceSource <- map["balanceSource"]
    }
}

// MARK: - Account
class Account: NSObject, NSCoding, Mappable {
    var accountType, accountNumber: String?

    init(accountType: String?, accountNumber: String?) {
        self.accountType = accountType
        self.accountNumber = accountNumber
    }
    
    override init() {
        
    }
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }
    
    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.accountType = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "accountType") as? String
        self.accountNumber = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "accountNumber") as? String
    }
    
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(accountType, forKey: "accountType")
        aCoder.encode(accountNumber, forKey: "accountNumber")
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        accountType <- map["accountType"]
        accountNumber <- map["accountNumber"]
    }
}

// MARK: - Balance
class Balance: NSObject, NSCoding, Mappable {
    
    var available, current, hold: Double?

    init(available: Double?, current: Double?, hold: Double?) {
        self.available = available
        self.current = current
        self.hold = hold
    }
    
    override init() {
        
    }
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }
    
    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.available = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "available") as? Double
        self.current = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "current") as? Double
        self.hold = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "hold") as? Double
    }
    
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(available, forKey: "available")
        aCoder.encode(current, forKey: "current")
        aCoder.encode(hold, forKey: "hold")
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        available <- map["available"]
        current <- map["current"]
        hold <- map["hold"]
    }
}


// Array Extension

import Foundation
import Alamofire

extension Array {
    func asParameters() -> Parameters {
        let arrayParametersKey = "arrayParametersKey"
        
        return [arrayParametersKey: self]
    }
}



// Class ArrayEncoding.swift


import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct ArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    public let options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions
    
    public init(options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = []) {
        self.options = options
    }
    
    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        let arrayParametersKey = "arrayParametersKey"
        
        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
        
        guard let parameters = parameters,
              let array = parameters[arrayParametersKey] else {
            return urlRequest
        }
        
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: options)
            
            if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content.Type") == nil {
                urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            }
            
            urlRequest.httpBody = data
        } catch {
            throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
        }
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

the json

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "data": {
        "account": {
            "accountType": "String",
            "accountNumber": "String"
        },
        "balance": {
            "available": 5.0,
            "current": 5.0,
            "hold": 5.0
        },
        "balanceSource": "string"
    }
}
```

Comment: `SwiftyJSON` and `ObjectMapper` are outdated. This is a good opportunity to switch to `Codable`

Comment: And please try to limit the amount of code you post.

Comment: @vadian I'm worried about conflicts between the way it's programmed above, and this new way, if I have to install different versions of Alamofire, so I'm trying to code this old way above.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Codable, like guys mention above, it is reduce your code base so much, works faster and you don't need to use other frameworks. Read more about that.

```
// MARK: - RealTimeBalance
struct RealTimeBalance: Codable {
    
    let code: Int?
    let data: DataStruct?
}

// MARK: - DataStruct
struct DataStruct: Codable {
    let account: Account?
    let balance: Balance?
    let balanceSource: String?
}

// MARK: - Account
struct Account: Codable {
    let accountType, accountNumber: String?
}

// MARK: - Balance
struct Balance: Codable {
    
    let available, current, hold: Double?
}
```

Also you can provide more details, set breakpoint/logs, maybe there something wrong with API, url, etc.

Comment: I'm worried about conflicts between the way it's programmed above, and the new way, if I have to install different versions of Alamofire, so I'm trying to code this old way above.

Comment: @bosozoku I think there's no chance for conflict, just refactor a little bit. I know that Alamofire works perfectly with Codable model and return your object already decoded. You need to change generic requestObject from <T: Mappable> to <T: Codable>. 
And also try to use .responseDecodable and get object directly or use .responseData and then in do { } catch { } decode your model